# Finding maximum bitwise and value in a two faced card

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

There are a list of cards with two numbers on it, one on the front and one on the back. I need to maximize the bitwise-and (&) by either taking the front or back of each card. And yes it should be done in minimum flips possible, as initially the cards are facing front and when I pick the number at the back, I am making a flip. I have solved this problem using the following code:

```
 for(int bit = 1<<30;bit > 0;bit>>=1){
        bool possible = true;
//Setting state to '0' for not flipping and '1' for flipping.'-1' means unset  
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
            if(state[i]==0 && !(A[i]&bit))possible = false;//A is the array to store front value
            else if(state[i]==1 && !(B[i]&bit))possible = false;// B is the array to store back value
            else if(!(A[i]&bit) &&!(B[i]&bit))possible = false;
        }
        if(!possible)continue;
        for(int i = 0;i < n;++i){**//SNIPPET TO REPLACE START**
            if (state[i] != -1)continue;
            if (!(A[i]&bit))state[i] = 1;
            else if (!(B[i]&bit))state[i] = 0;//SNIPPET TO REPLACE END
        }
       /*USING THIS SNIPPET GIVED WRONG ANSWER
       for(int i = 0;i < n;++i){
            if(state[i]!=-1)continue;
            if(A[i] & bit)state[i]=0;
            else if(B[i] & bit)state[i]=1;
        }
       */
    }
    int ans;
    int count_ = 0;
    ans = (1 << 30) - 1;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        if(state[i]==1){
            ans&=B[i];
            count_++;
        }
        else ans&=A[i];
    }
```

As explained in the comments of the code, I feel the both snippet should work just fine. I maybe missing some edge case why the snippet I commented does not work as the one I actually used in the code for execution.

Comment: This might belong on [codereview.se]

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How `state` is declared and initialized will make a difference in your code, etc..

Comment: @kabanus, the Code Review site is for working, complete code so posters can suggest improvements to the code